# How to make button and checkbox fixed on the bottom of a DIV

Tags: html, css

How can I have my button and checkbox fixed at the bottom of my div. I am able to get my scroll-able working as well. My problem is the button and the checkbox are not fixed at the bottom.

So when I populate the div with text, the text overflows the button and the checkbox but how can I make the text be contained in the scroll-able and not overflow the button and the checkbox?

```css
#chk {
  float: left
}

.btn {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<div style="height:40%; overflow: scroll;" class="panel" id="panel">

 <!--inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here) -->

  <input id="chk" type="checkbox" /> <!-- should be on the left bottom of the div -->

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Button</button> <!--should be on the right bottom of the div (opposite the checkbox)-->

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please include the CSS you have tried?

Comment: @JoeLissner i have included my  css for the button and checkbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that I have added a wrapper div around the two interactive element.
Let me know if you have any limitation in the markup that doesn't allow you to wrap them in a container and we'll find another solution in that case.

```css
#panel {
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
    
.panel-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 95%; /* to be resized as it suits you */
  background-color: white;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: .5rem;
}
#chk {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:40%; overflow: scroll;" class="panel" id="panel">

inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here)


  <div class="panel-bottom">
    <input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Button</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Probably want to add padding to the bottom of `#panel` so that the input/button don't flow over the text.

Comment: panel , relative?  it moves other elements on another panel on my screen and i am not able to give it height

Comment: Are you using the same id for more than one element?

Comment: nope but the panel is above another div element and it pushes the div element below it when the text is filling up

Comment: I need to see the rest of the code to take in account what happens to other elements you are dealing with.

Comment: i think @JoeLissner first point is necessary because currently it is overflowing

Comment: Look at the image

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

Keep the `input` and the `button` elements out of your `.panel` `div`:

```
<div style="height:40%; overflow-y: scroll;" class="panel" id="panel">

 <!--inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here) -->

</div>
<div id = "inpAndBtn">
  <input id="chk" type="checkbox" /> <!-- should be on the left bottom of the div -->

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Button</button> <!--should be on the right bottom of the div (opposite the checkbox)-->
</div>
```

And add the following styles:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#chk {
  float: left
}

.btn {
  float: right
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent container should be positioned relative.

```
<div style="height:300px;position:relative;" class="panel" id="panel">
    <div style="height:250px; overflow-y: scroll;">
 <!--inner part of the div which contains the text (scrollable is applied here) -->
    <div>
 <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;height:50px;" >
  <input id="chk" type="checkbox" /> <!-- should be on the left bottom of the div -->
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Button</button> <!--should be on the right bottom of the div (opposite the checkbox)-->
  </div>
</div>
```